# FCM onReceived method to implement Shortcut Badger library

Tags: android, notifications, push, counter

I found this library (https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) to implement app icon counter badge in android.
badge works when i implement in activity. but i want to implement this when push notification is received. i currently have the initialize code in onMesseageReceived() method in Firebase messaging service but its not working.

see code below: 
Thanks for your help

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Logger.i("Received message");




    //Shourtcut Badger
    int badgeCount = 1;
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount);



    //parseNotification(bundle);
    parseNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {


        String str = remoteMessage.getData().get("notification");
        String from_user = "";
        String message = "";
        String name = "";
        int type = 0;
        if (str != null && str.length() > 0) {


            try {
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(str);

                from_user = jobj.optString("from");
                message = jobj.optString("message");
                name = jobj.optString("name");

                type = Integer.parseInt(jobj.optString("type"));



                if (type == LIKE_STATUS) {
                    handleStatusLikeByFriendPush(jobj, "" + type);
                } else if (type == PHOTO_UPDATE) {
                    handlePhotoUpdateByFriendPush(jobj, "" + type);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            message = "";//bundle.getString("message");
            from_user = "";//bundle.getString("source");

            if (from_user != null && from_user.contains(IMHandler.AT + IMHandler.DOMAIN)) {
                from_user = from_user.substring(0, from_user.indexOf(IMHandler.AT));
            }

            showNotification(from_user, message, type, name);

        }



    }



}










public void handleStatusLikeByFriendPush(JSONObject jobj, String pushType) {
 // method 

}

public void handlePhotoLikeByFriendPush(JSONObject jobj, String pushType) {
```

//method implement
    }

```
}
private void showNotification(String from, String body, int type, String name) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After lots of research i understand implementation of this Shortcut badge is not working in FCM service. I Am Able to resolve this issue by simply calling a a custom service from FCM service each time push notification is received and the custom service handles the badge codes  and there affter destroys itself.

This way is working perfectly.